# Changing the Scaffold's body dynamically

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm new to flutter and in need of help with this project I'm working on.

I'm trying to change the content of the `body` property of the `Scaffold` widget dynamically based on what the user clicked on the `bottomNavigationBar`.

I am trying to use the Provider state management 'cause I'm trying to learn while I'm creating some apps.

Here's what I got;

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(Pananta());
}

class Pananta extends StatefulWidget {
  Pananta({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Pananta> createState() => _PanantaState();
}

class _PanantaState extends State<Pananta> {
  int pageIndex = 0;

  void changePage() {
    setState(() {
      Provider.of<ScreenData>(context).pageIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int screenDataIndex = Provider.of<ScreenData>(context).selectedIndex;
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ScreenData>(
      create: (_) => ScreenData(),
      builder: (context, child) =>
          ScreenData.pages[context.watch<ScreenData>().selectedIndex],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
        home: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: screenDataIndex == 0
                ? ScreenData.pages[0]
                : ScreenData.pages[screenDataIndex],
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomBarMenu(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**screen_data.dart**

```
class ScreenData extends ChangeNotifier {
  int pageIndex = 0;

  static List<Widget> pages = [
    const HomePage(),
    UserProfile(),
  ];

  set selectedpage(int selected) {
    pageIndex = selected;
  }

  int get selectedIndex {
    notifyListeners();
    return pageIndex;
  }
}
```

**The error that I'm getting:**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Pananta(dirty, state:
_PanantaState#683a3):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ScreenData> above this Pananta Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Pananta is under your MultiProvider/Provider<ScreenData>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:


 ` Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }`


  consider using `builder` like so:


 `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }`
```

I think the `int screenDataIndex = Provider.of<ScreenData>(context).selectedIndex;` line is what's causing the issue, because when I remove it and set the `body` to `ScreenData.pages[0]` the error goes away -- I can't figure out what to do with it. Any help or articles that I can read will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest separating the context to read the provider, and using `Consumer`  widget inside widget tree.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ScreenData>(
      create: (_) => ScreenData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
        home: Pananta(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Pananta extends StatefulWidget {
  Pananta({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Pananta> createState() => _PanantaState();
}

class _PanantaState extends State<Pananta> {
  int pageIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(body: Consumer<ScreenData>(
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          final currentPage = value.pageIndex;

          return currentPage == 0
              ? ScreenData.pages[0]
              : ScreenData.pages as Widget;
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it did made the errors go away. However, it seems that the page is not rebuilding. The value of `currentPage` is updating based on the selected button, but the screen/page is not updating. My code ended up with:

`body: Consumer<ScreenData>(
 builder: (context, value, child) {
 final currentPage = value.pageIndex;
 return ScreenData.pages[currentPage];
 }
}`

Comment: you needed to notify the listener while changing value like `set selectedpage(int selected) {
    pageIndex = selected;  notifyListners();//this one
  }`

Comment: Thank you. Got it running and working! :)

Answer (score 0):

try a configuration like this:

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Create a list of widget and put inside screens you want show.Create relatives BottomNavigationBarItem and the onTap function which update index with selectedIndex.
I think your code is harder than necessary. Try and let me know. Nice coding!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I understand that my code is a bit too much for what I'm trying to accomplish. I just want to learn about state managements as I go along. I'll definitely have this bookmarked for future reference. Cheers!